# CSS transition from direction

Tags: css, css-transitions, opacity, fade

I know how to make fade CSS transition, but is there a solution to do fade out from top to bottom?

Here is my code

```
.navbar-default{
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

I need animation from top to bottom, any suggestion?

Comment: What type of fade are you using? Opacity fade?

Comment: Yes, but i want to showing from tom to bottom, no fade just slide from top to bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is impossible with pure CSS. We can only work around the situation only when we can recreate the background (and perhaps foreground) with pure CSS, meaning a solid color or *maybe* a gradient. This is because using `opacity` affects the entire element, and cannot go in a direction like you want it to

As a result, I opted to use a pseudo element and some gradients. Since, in my case, the base element is black and the background is white, I created a gradient that fades from black to white for the bottom half then stays white for the top half. You can then make the pseudo element twice as large tall as the original element, place it at `top:-200%`, and use `transform:translateY(100%)` to *essentially* fade the element from the top. In reality this is just covering it up in a way that deceives our eyes. All of this is made possible by `overflow:hidden` on the element

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/KGm9u/) (webkit & unprefixed only at the moment)

```
.elem {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background:black;
    margin:20px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
}
.elem:before {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    height:200%;
    width:100%;
    top:-200%;
    background:white;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff 0%, #ffffff 50%, #000000 100%);
    transition:all 0.5s ease;
    left:0;
}
.elem:hover:before {
    transform:translateY(100%);
}
```

[This tool](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) may help you generate the gradients you need

There is likely a way to do it without pseudo elements using javascript